# not able to make hasMany relationship in eloquent laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Hi I am new to laravel and trying to make one to many relationship where I am trying to get customer name from customers and order_no against the customer name from orders table, here is code

```
//--customer Model
class customer extends Model {
  public function order(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\order');
 }
}

//-- order Model
class order extends Model {
    public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\customer');
       }
     }

  //--controller
  public function searchRecord(){
  $customer = customer::all();
  return view('orders.searchRecord')->with('customer', $customer);
  }

  //--View

 @foreach($customer as $customer)                                        
 {{$customer->customer_name}}<br />
 @endforeach
```

when I use `{{$customer->customer_name}}` it prints all customer name fine, but when I use `{{$customer->order}}` it prints the whole json of order table, but if I `{{$customer->order->order_no}}` it gives error undefined property $order_no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your **customer->order** relation as **one-to-many**, which means that a **single customer can have multiple orders**. Therefore, when you access **$customer->order** you are accessing a **Collection** object that stores all customer's order, not a single order. There is no **order_no** property in **Collection** class, that's why you're getting the error.

One way to access invidual orders you'll need to iterate through the collection:

```
foreach ($customer->order as $order) {
  echo $order->order_no;
}
```

Comment: so i shoud make foreach loop in side foreach?

Comment: I don't know what you want to display there. But yes, if you want to iterate through all customers and their orders, you'll need a nested foreach